# Midpoint convex bounded function is continuous

Tags: continuity, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

I'm reading a proof of the following statement:

> Let $f: (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a midpoint convex (i.e. $f(1/2(x+y)) \leq 1/2f(x) + 1/2f(y)$) function that is bounded. Then $f$ is continuous.

Here is a proof that I found here: [Proving continuity of $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137909/proving-continuity-of-f)

To prove that a bounded midpoint convex is continuous, argue by contradiction. Supose $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0\in(a,b)$. Without loss of generality we may assume $x_0=0$, $f(x_0)=0$.

**First step.**  There exists a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset(a,b)$, such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=m\ne0$. We may assume that $m>0$.

**Second step.** The sequence $\{2\,x_n\}$ also converges to $0$ and
$$
f(x_n)=f\Bigl(\frac{0+2\,x_n}2\Bigr)\le\frac{f(0)+f(2\,x_n)}2\implies f(2\,x_n)\ge2\,f(x_n)\implies\liminf f(2\,x_n)\ge2\,m.
$$
Iteration shows that
$$
\liminf f(2^k\,x_n)\ge2^k\,m,
$$
which is impossible since $f$ is bounded.

**Question**: Why can we assume $m > 0$?

Comment: Consider the function $f+2|m|$ which is also mid point convex.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat

Comment: but that function wont satisfy $f(x_0)=0$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Good point. I didn't think of that.

Comment: I found a simple proof of the theorem in question if you would like

Comment: Sure! That's even better.

Comment: @Jorge I'm going to sleep right now, but I look forward to see your answer once I wake up. Bye!

Comment: I'm done, I also found how to solve the initial problem

Comment: If we have that the sequence converges to a negative $m$ you can take the negative values of the $a_i$, and by the convecity we will have that these values are all greater than the negatives of the original values

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo When will you post the alternative proof? Can't wait to see it! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I forgot to undelete it, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume $a<0<b$, $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and $f(0)=0$.

If not we can solve it by shifting the function horizontal and vertically and stretching horizontally.

Notice that since $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that we can find $x$ as small as possible such that $|f(x)|>\epsilon$

Notice that if $f(x) < 0$ we have that $f(-x)>0$ because $f(x)+f(-x)\ge 0$.

So without loss of generality $f(x)>0$ and now we have $f(x)\leq f(2x)/2\leq f(4x)/4\dots$

This tells us $f(2^nx)\geq 2^n\epsilon$.

Of course we need to make $x$ small so that $2^nx$ is inside the interval

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Thanks!

Comment: I was wrong, but we can multiply it by $-1$.

Comment: But multiplying by -1 does not preserve midpoint convexity?

Comment: I also don't know why they assume that the limit of $f(x_n)$ exists

Comment: They can assume that because $f$ is bounded, so $f(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense

Comment: But don't we have a problem? If $f$ is midpoint convex, then $-f$ is not necessarily midpoint-convex. I think absolute value $x \mapsto |x|$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Yeah, my reasoning is not sound you are right.

Comment: I think we cannot assume it, but as long as the limit is nonzero we can do the same thing

Comment: Oh nvm ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I believe the proof fails if $m < 0$. But look at the comment above. I think that solves it.

Comment: Hi. Did you use the assumption that $a<0 <b$? I can't see where it is used

Comment: Also, I don't see how we can suppose wlog that $f(x) > 0$. If $f$ is continuous at the left, but not at the right in $x_0$, then you won't get that $|f(-x)| > \epsilon$ for example.

Comment: It isn't used, but I need for $0$ to be inside of the domain because it is the point of discontinuity. If you change $0$ with something else the numbers get a bit messy (they aren't $x,2x,4x$ etc

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. What about my second comment above? As it now stands, the proof only holds for positive functions.

Comment: $f(-x)>\epsilon$ because $f(x) + f(-x)\geq 0$, not because of continuity.

Comment: I see! Thanks! I will go through it in detail again.

Comment: In fact this idea can be used to restore the original proof you had. Instead of taking $a_n$ you take $x_0-a_n$ and then take a convergent subsequence of it. ( that is the reason why you can take $m>0$ in the original proof you supplied).

Comment: I find this proof a lot easier to understand to be honest. Thanks again for that!

Comment: Sure, no problem !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=m<0.$$
Let $y_n=-x_n$, then
$$0=f(0)=f\left(\frac{x_n+y_n}{2}\right)\leq\frac{f(x_n)+f(y_n)}{2},$$
so $f(y_n)\geq-f(x_n)$, then
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)\geq\limsup_{n\to\infty}(-f(x_n))
=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-f(x_n))=-m>0.$$
So there exists subsequences $\{f(y_{_{n_k}})\}$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}f(y_{_{n_k}})=\limsup_{n\to\infty}f(y_n)\geq-m>0.$$