# $f(x)$: Jensen's inequality holds but not convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

It is known, that if $f(x):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a **continuous** function defined on $(a,b)$ such that
$$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\leq \frac{1}{2} f(x) + \frac{1}{2} f(y) \tag{*}$$ for all $x,y \in (a,b)$, then $f$ is convex.

Hence continuity is a **satisfactory** condition for the convexity given $(*)$.

1. Is there an example of a function $g$ that is not continuous and
   satisfies $(*)$?
2. Is there an example of a function $g$ that is not
   convex and satisfies $(*)$?

I am pretty sure such a question has been asked, yet I can't find a thing.

Comment: Property (*) is called “midpoint convex”. There are [various Q&As](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=midpoint+convex) about when midpoint-convexity implies convexity (e.g. if $f$ is continuous, or just bounded)

Comment: Thanks! Knowing the name of the property helped hah!

Comment: Here is a quite strong result: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4354554/42969

Comment: With the axiom of choice, Hamel proved that there are discontinuous functions satisfying the Cauchy equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for any $x, y\in\mathbf R.$

Comment: Refer to https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01457624