# Why is this function almost Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, functional-equations

We are still in the saga of solving the 2002 qualifier. [This question 6b](https://www.math.harvard.edu/media/quals90-02.pdf) has stumped me and I am mostly clueless about it:

> Say $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded with a finite constant $B$ such that:
> $$\frac{|f(x+y)+f(x-y)-2f(x)|}{|y|}\leq B$$
> Prove there exists $M(\lVert f \rVert_\infty, B)$ such that for all $x\not=y$:
> $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M |x-y|\left(1+\ln_+(\frac{1}{|x-y|})\right)$$
> Where $\ln_+(x)=\max \{0,\ln(x)\}$

Intuitively this means that away from $y=x$, $f(x+y)\rightarrow f(x)$  linearly. Close to $x$, it is still true $f(x+y)\rightarrow f(x)$ but it is slightly perturbed by $\ln_+$. Here are a couple of facts which have gotten me nowhere:

**Fact 0. The inequality in $B$ would be an approximation for $f''(x)$ if it were divided by $y^2$ instead of $y$.**

This is particularly useless, because we have no regularity associated with $f$. Even if we did $|f''(x)|\leq \lim M/|y|=\infty$ so this observation cannot be of any help.

**Fact 1. $\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} |f(x-y)-f(x)|$ exists.**

One has by inverted triangle inequality that:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}||f(x+y)-f(x)|-|f(x-y)-f(x)||\leq \lim_{y\rightarrow 0 }B|y|=0$$

But taking away the modulus and changing $\lim$ to $\limsup$:
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\sup_{y\in[-a,a]}(|f(x+y)-f(x)|-|f(x-y)-f(x)|)=0$$

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\sup_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x+y)-f(x)|\leq\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\inf_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x-y)-f(x)|$$

But as we are taking the infimum in a symetric interval, hence we may write:
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\sup_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x+y)-f(x)|\leq\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\inf_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x+y)-f(x)|\leq \lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\sup_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x+y)-f(x)|$$

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\sup_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x+y)-f(x)|=\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}\inf_{y\in [-a,a]}|f(x+y)-f(x)|$$

This means that $\lim |f(x+y)-f(x)|$ exists.

**Fact 2. There is the obvious $y=y-x$ substitution**

$$\frac{|f(y)+f(2x-y)-2f(x)|}{|y-x|}\leq B$$
$$|f(y)-f(x)|\leq B|y-x|+|f(2x-y)-f(x)|$$

Comment: I am not sure if your proof of “Fact 1” is correct. You have $$\limsup_{y\to 0} |f(x+y)-f(x)|-|f(x-y)-f(x)| \le \limsup_{y\to 0} |f(x+y)-f(x)| - \liminf_{y\to 0} |f(x-y)-f(x)|$$ but you would need $\ge$.

Comment: Shoot. You are right. I must have been tired. :(

Comment: I write plenty of wrong proofs when I'm completely alert!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set $K = \Vert f \Vert_\infty$. In order to simplify the notation a bit we fix  $y \in \Bbb R$ and consider the function
$$
 g: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R , \, g(u) = f(y+u) - f(y) \, .
$$
Note that $\Vert g \Vert_\infty \le 2K$. We will prove that there is a constant $M = M(K, B)$ such that
$$ \tag{$*$}
 |g(u)| \le M |u| \left(1+ \log^+ \frac {1}{|u|} \right)
$$
for all $u \ne 0$. Then
$$
 |f(x) - f(y)| = |g(x-y)| \le M |x-y| \left(1+ \log^+ \frac {1}{|x-y|} \right)
$$
for all $x \ne y$.

---

*Proof of $(*)$:* For $|u| \ge 1$ is
$$
 |g(u)| \le 2K \le 2K|u| \, ,
$$
that is the desired linear upper bound $(*)$ with $M=2K$.

Now we consider the case $0 < |u| < 1$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
 2 |g(u)| - |g(2u)| &\le |g(2u) - 2g(u)| \\
&= | f(y+2u) + f(y) - 2 f(y+u)| \\
&\le B |u| \, ,
\end{align}
$$
using the given inequality with $\tilde x = y+u$ and $\tilde y = u$. It follows that
$$
 |g(u)| \le \frac 12 |g(2u)| + \frac{B|u|}{2} \, .
$$
We can apply this repeatedly to $2u, 4u, 8u, \ldots$:
$$
\begin{align}
 |g(u)| &\le \frac 12 \left( \frac 12 |g(4u)| + B|u| \right) + \frac{B|u|}{2}
= \frac 14 |g(4u)| + B|u| \\
 &\le \frac 14 \left( \frac 12 |g(8u)| + 2B|u| \right) + B|u| 
= \frac 18 |g(8u)| + \frac{3B|u|}{2} \\
&\le \cdots \\
&\le \frac 1{2^n} |g(2^nu)| + \frac{nB|u|}{2}
\le \frac {2K}{2^n}  + \frac{nB|u|}{2}
\end{align}
$$
for all nonnegative integers $n$.  Setting $n = \lfloor \log(1/|u|)\rfloor$ gives
$$
 |g(u)| \le 4 K |u| + \frac{B|u|}{2} \log \frac{1}{|u|}
 = |u| \left( 4K + \frac B2 \log \frac{1}{|u|} \right)
$$
and that is $(1)$ with $M=\max(4K, B/2)$.

Combining the results for $0 < |u| < 1$ and $|u| \ge 1$ we see that $(*)$ holds for all $ u \ne 0$ with  $M=\max(4K, B/2)$, and that concludes the proof.

---

*Remarks:*

- The above proof is inspired by proofs of “midpoint convex + bounded function $\implies$ continuous”, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137909/42969) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3637220/42969).
- As in the case of midpoint convex functions, the boundedness condition is crucial (compare [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/71019/42969)). Any non-continuous solution of [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ satisfies the given condition (with $B=0$), but not the conclusion. Such non-continuous solutions exists, and they are necessarily unbounded.

Comment: @Kadmos: Here's another way to think about the translation invariance, and maybe it will help. The given condition depends on the value of the function at three points—at some central point $x$, and at two equally distant peripheral points—as well as the distance between that central point and either of the other points. The conclusion to draw is somewhat confusing because it uses the same names for different purposes, but it depends only on the distance between two points $x$ and $y$, and the difference between their function values. Both are therefore unaffected by a sideways sliding of $f$.

Comment: It might be helpful to replace $x$ and $y$ in that conclusion (the "to be proven" part) by two wholly different variable names—say, $s$ and $t$. It could prevent one from going down some blind alleys.

Comment: @Kadmos: I have rewritten the proof, is it clearer now?

Comment: Much, much clearer. Thank you so much. If I could I would upvote your answer twice. :)

Comment: @Kadmos: You are welcome, it was fun to figure this out! – I have added some remarks about how I came up with the proof, and why the boundedness condition is important.